# File Transfer only complete if server disconnects

Tags: c, linux, file, transfer

I'm having some problem with the code below. It is designed to receive a file from a server. It works 100% fine as long as the server disconnects after sending.

If the server doesn't disconnect, then the transfer doesn't complete client side, and the client continues to wait for bytes and doesn't break out of the loop properly (when fr_block_sz == 0), as it does when the server disconnects after receiving the file. It sits in the loop endlessly.

I'd like to be able to receive a file and keep the connection open afterwards. Any advice? Thanks.

EDIT: Per Casey's advice I'm now monitoring the amount of bytes written via the commented code below, but am getting odd behavior causing file transfers to not complete properly. Can anyone see any wrong doing in my code? Thanks.

EDIT 2: I've posted debugging info in regards to my problem to try to make it clearer.

```
// Reciever of file (client)
int TotalSize = 7374; // hardcoded file size to expect
int FileSize = 0; // counter
int fr_block_sz = 0; 
while ((fr_block_sz = recv(sd, revbuf, 1, 0)) > 0)  //LENGTH == 512
{
    if (fr_block_sz < 0)
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
            continue;
        else
            printf("File write failed");

        if (fr_block_sz == 0)           
            break; //done

        // edit based on comment - does not change behavior
        if(FilzeSize > TotalSize)
        {
            fr_block_sz = fr_block_sz - (FileSize - TotalSize);   
        }            

        int write_sz = fwrite(revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);
        // add total bytes recvd every loop
        FileSize += write_sz;
        // if bytes recieved equals expect file size, break
        if (FileSize >= TotalSize)// this is where my problem is, as sometimes 
                                  // FileSize == 7376 or 7672 instead of 7374
                                  // When it fails, fr_block_sz == 24 which
                                  // i don't think is right either. Even when
                                  // set to break if FileSize > TotalSize, the 
                                  // loop still doesn't complete
            break;
        printf("Recieved size == %i of %i \n", FilzeSize, TotalSize);

        if (write_sz < fr_block_sz)
        {
            printf("File write failed");
        }

        bzero(revbuf, 1);

}
printf("Transfer complete \n");
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
Recieved size == 512 of 7374 
Recieved size == 1024 of 7374 
Recieved size == 1368 of 7374 
Recieved size == 1880 of 7374 
Recieved size == 2392 of 7374 
Recieved size == 2736 of 7374 
Recieved size == 3248 of 7374 
Recieved size == 3760 of 7374 
Recieved size == 4104 of 7374 
Recieved size == 4616 of 7374 
Recieved size == 5128 of 7374 
Recieved size == 5472 of 7374 
Recieved size == 5984 of 7374 
Recieved size == 6496 of 7374 
Recieved size == 6840 of 7374 
Recieved size == 7352 of 7374 
Recieved size == 7376 of 7374
```

Once it gets here, the client will wait here forever in the loop and nothing happens. I then have to manually stop the program from the console, and after the program has been stopped, only 4096  bytes of the file have been written. I wold be most appreciative if someone could shed light on my problem, or the "normal" way to do this. Thank you.

EDIT - FIXED (sort of). I found a way to make it work reliably 100% every time, and that is by changing LENGTH == 1, so setting a one byte buffer size, and if the kernel is writing byte for byte it can't get short/long reads. This works, but obviously isn't the fastest solution. I would still like to hear any others anyone has and thanks for your help Rajal.

Comment: So you have to look at the server code instead

Comment: Unrelated: Filling a buffer with zeroes before you fill it with other data is pointless.

Comment: Casey - fixed, bbonev - vague comment, follow up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your client doesn't know when the file transfer is complete if the server doesn't close the connection. How could you communicate that fact?

Comment: I've tried coding the server to send a confirm byte after send, and it does. It only works when the server disconnects though, and then the client writes the file + 1 byte (which was the confirm) and I couldn't figure out how to do comparisons against specific bytes within the loop. I assume I need to have the server send a byte, let's say 0xAA, then when the client gets that byte it can break out of the loop?

Comment: But then what happens if there's a 0xAA in the file data? Remember that you can't trust that you get chunks of data from `recv` divided up in exactly the same way they were sent: you're guaranteed ordering, but the chunks could be split or merged.

Comment: Hint: Have the server tell the client the length of the data before sending the data.

Comment: Yes I see by setting a counter and doing counter += write_sz every iteration you can see how much of the file is written and break out when it reaches a certain size. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Casey, I went back and posted what had initially worked, but now I'm receiving write sizes sometimes 2 bytes bigger than the file size, and it's causing the code to hang. Do you know what's wrong w/my code above?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following some protocol between client and server. An example I can show as below.

1. Assume in server as well as in the client that the first 4 bytes for any communication is the size of file. The first 4 bytes is sent by the server for each established connection and till the file is fully sent. For another file /conenction the server will again send 4 bytes telling the size of file.
2. So, the first 4 bytes to client will indicate exactly how much data it has to process.
3. The client will read only 4 bytes initially instead of assuming full buffer as data convert the 4 bytes to integer so that it can get exact number of bytes to receive. There is no need for confirm byte, it is useless to have it here.
4. Once the received bytes is equal to the bytes sent by the server assume file is received and server can close the connection.
5. You can assume next byte after receiving the number of bytes in file as an Indicator that the server is ready to send another file or also if you want to receive one file per connection then if you receive extra bytes in buffer, just discard it.

There can be other ways of receiving files as well as we sometime see in download managers. like breaking the files in chunks or receiving multiple files using the same connection but I believe once you setup a protocol the enhancements can be figured out easily.

Hope it helps.

Pseudo

just discard any byte(s) exceeding the file size. try the following before fwrite.

```
    if(FilzeSize > TotalSize)
    {
        fr_block_sz = fr_block_sz - (FilezeSize - TotalSize);   
    }
    int write_sz = fwrite(revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);
```

it should write the revbuf excluding the last 2 bytes.

Regards
Kajal

Comment: Thanks for the response Kajal. I've successfully done steps 1 - 3 (albeit a bit different). However on step 4 often times it will just sit in the loop and the file won't complete successfully, although it did once.

Comment: Also, for step 5, can you post some pseudo code as to how to disregard extra bytes, and do you see anything wrong with the code I've posted? Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Try out sending multiple files one after another in same connection :)

Comment: I'd like to do that but I need to get one successful first. I posted debugging print statements in my code and posted the console output, it seems like the kernel wants to write 2 extra bytes every time. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: I also think you misunderstood me Kajal in reference to #4, I don't want the server to have close the connection everytime a file is sent.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "discard any byte(s) exceeding the file size"?

Comment: just discard any byte(s) exceeding the file size. try the following before fwrite.

if(FilzeSize > TotalSize)
{
 fr_block_sz = fr_block_sz - (FilezeSize - TotalSize); 
}
int write_sz = fwrite(revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);

it should write the revbuf excluding the last 2 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the input Kajal but that doesn't work, I edited my code to reflect your change and the behavior is exactly the same. Is there a mistake in mycode?

Comment: The reason this code doesn't work for me is because FileSize is calculated AFTER fwrite, so that comparison is not happening until the next iteration, which is after the call that has written too many bytes. There's also the problem that even though the program says x amount of bytes have been written, the kernel isn't actually writing them as when I stop my program, only 4096 bytes get written, every time. Any other ideas Kajal? Thanks.